# align a picutre in a placeholder - how to do it bootstrap

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4

i came across a problem, when i upload a picture to my new post with thumbnail it shows under thumbnail section in my bootstrap card where iam supposed to put a text. I'd like to put a picutre in the gray background of the card.

```html
      <div class="row">
        <% @posts.each do |post| %>   <!--  no %= because this isn an output, tylko przy pokazywaniu zmiennych tego sie uzywa -->
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm ">
            <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="100%" height="225" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Thumbnail"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#55595c"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#eceeef" dy=".3em"><%= image_tag post.image.url(:medium) %></text></svg>
            <div class="card-body">
              <p class="card-text"><h3><%= post.title %> </h3> <%= post.body %></p>
              <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                <div class="btn-group">
                        <%= link_to "View", post_path(post), :class =>'btn btn-md btn-outline-secondary' %>
                        <%= link_to "Edit", edit_post_path(post), :class =>'btn btn-md btn-outline-secondary' %>
                  </div>
    <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

<% end %>

</div>
```

Screenshot with the problem https://iv.pl/image/placeholder1.Gt2qZ7Y

Comment: Check out this [pen](https://codepen.io/ni_l/pen/jOrWdoB?editors=1000). You can put images and make use of bootstrap cards as shown over there! For full-page view, click [here](https://codepen.io/ni_l/full/jOrWdoB)! @bubuq3

Comment: Guys please stick with English language, otherwise post your questions/comments on the other versions of Stackoverflow: please see this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297734/10339463

Comment: Ok, sorry about that. Could you tell me where am I supposed to put <%= image_tag post.image.url(:medium) %> in this code?